# Laravel Eloquent relationships - hasOne?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a question table which has a type_id column. The value defined here relates to the QuestionTypes model.

Question Table:

```
--------------------------
| id | title   | type_id |
--------------------------
| 1  | apple?  | 2       |
| 3  | banana? | 2       |
| 4  | kiwi?   | 2       |
| 5  | pear?   | 3       |
--------------------------
```

QuestionTypes

```
----------------
| id | title   |
----------------
| 1  | multi   |
| 2  | single  |
| 3  | free    |
----------------
```

In the Questions Model I have:

```
public function type()
{
    return $this->hasOne(QuestionType::class);
}
```

I would like to print the title from questiontypes table but when I try to output in the view using `$question->type->title` I get:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'x__questiontypes.questions_id' in 'where clause'
(SQL: select * from `x__questiontypes` where `x__questiontypes`.`questions_id` = 2 and `x__questiontypes`.`questions_id` is not null limit 1
```

Have I mixed up the relationships?

Comment: Try using the `belongsTo()` method instead of `hasOne()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution via [Attaching a hasOne model to another Laravel/Eloquent model without specifying id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26178049/attaching-a-hasone-model-to-another-laravel-eloquent-model-without-specifying-id?rq=1)

Updated to Questions model:

```
public function type()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(QuestionType::class, 'type_id');
}
```

Added to QuestionType model:

```
public function questions()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Question::class, 'type_id');
}
```